# What does the sky look like from the moon?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, moon

From pictures taken on the moon, it appears that there are no stars visible in the sky, but I do not know if this is an effect due to cameras.

1. What is the actual appearance of the sky on the moon?
2. Are stars visible?
3. Is there any difference between the daytime and nighttime sky on the moon (other than the sun’s absence)?
4. When the sun sets, does the surface of the moon instantly become completely dark?
5. Similarly, when the sun sets, would the environment instantly become pitch black?

Comment: I hope that we get night time pictures by the new Indian moon rover to be absolutely sure about it.

Comment: That is a lot of questions.

Answer (score 32):

Quote from [Buzz Aldrin](https://buzzaldrin.com/john-glenn-buzz-aldrin-others-recount-life-changing-views-from-space/):

> “Obviously, when we touched down on the moon, we were very relieved. The immediate surface was very powdery, as best we could see looking down from 15 feet. Off in the distance was a very clear horizon, maybe with a boulder. And, of course, the brightness of the sunlit surface was almost like looking out at sunlit snow. Your pupils close down, just as in orbit when the sun is on the spacecraft. The sky is black as can be, but there’s no way you can see stars. They’re there, of course, but you can’t make them out because they’re too faint with all the ambient light in your eyes. I was impressed with the total “magnificent” desolation I saw in front of me: black sky, no stars and the horizon clearly curving away.”

Comment: Whereas you should probably see them much better than from earth, when you land on the night side of the moon, since there's no atmosphere. This answer does not yet address all points of OP

Comment: (((*remark about answers that are only quotes without any input from the creator of said answer*))). - - -  And then I noticed this was physics.se

Comment: I wish I had some personal experience to complement what Buzz Aldrin said. :) To tell the truth I tried to find a video of a simulation in Stellarium that would cover more of the question. I didn't find anything good.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, maybe. The astronaut would be seeing the dark sky through a curved sheet of transparent material (helmet), which could result in quite the diffusion and distortion. We might not know until someone tries it. Has anybody done an EVA while in the Earth’s shadow? Probably not, for safety reasons. That would be very similar, maybe even better (no scratches on the visor from moon dust to contend with)

Answer (score 21):

That's because those photos are showing the black backdrop of the studio where they were taken...kidding.

The stars are not visible on the Moon, at least in photos, because the lunar surface in sunlight was so bright that the stars were washed out.  No camera (nor the human eye, usually) has the dynamic range to process something very bright next to something less bright.  If the aperture were open wide enough and the exposure long enough to collect enough light to image the dim source, it would collect so much light from the bright source in that time that this latter light would overpower everything else, and you would not get a comprehensible image.  Try to take a picture of a candle flame with the mid-day Sun in the background.

As for human eyes, astronaut testimony may confirm stars were visible on the Moon when looking away from the surface.  I do not have that information.  I tend to think if a camera were pointing straight at the sky with "blinders" on to block surface light, you would see the stars just as well as in empty space.

The thing to remember on the Moon is, the lack of atmosphere means there is no refraction or scattering of light.  The only light you see in any direction is the light that came from that direction.  If the Sun is in your field of view, you see it.  If you turn your back to it, the sky is as dark as night.  Anywhere around the Sun is also as dark as night (though you may not see stars, as mentioned before). When the Sun sets, its light immediately disappears, though you would still have light from the Earth, so it may not be pitch black, but would be much darker.

Comment: You can compare an Earthlit sky on the moon to a moonlit sky on Earth. Note that the Earth is larger than the Moon, and that the Earth is substantially covered in white clouds, so the Earth will be substantially brighter than the Moon. Earth will go through phases (crescent, gibbous, full, gibbous, crescent) as senn from the Moon, but will not rise or set, because the Moon's "day" has the same length as the month.

Comment: @rob Well, the sky on the Moon is not lit by the Earth at all because it is a pretty good vacuum. (You probably mean that you see the Earth from the Moon the same way you see the Moon from Earth, on a clear night.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Whoops, yes. I was thinking of the illumination of the Moon's surface: a full Moon is bright enough to cast obvious shadows and to read surprisingly fine print. But I wrote "sky" instead out of habit.

Comment: @rob More than just clouds (but they are important): the moon is grey rock with an albedo of 0.12, worn asphalt.  The Earth is 0.3!  In total, the Earth is 34x brighter than the Moon (on the other surface).  The Earth on the thinnest (not completely gone) day of its 28 day cycle is about as bright as a full moon.

Comment: When the Sun sets (as per the usual definition of sunset, i.e. hiding of the photosphere below the horizon), you still can see the corona.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind with regards to astronauts being able to "look away" and see stars - all the moon missions were timed such that the astronauts would be in the early moon "morning" (before the surface got too hot), so the sun would have been low in the "sky" each time, making it more likely stars would be visible if they were facing away from the sun (because the sun's rays were striking the moon's surface at an angle)

Comment: OP asked "when the sun sets, would the environment instantly become pitch black?" and your answer says "When the Sun sets, its light immediately disappears", which seems at the least misleading. There should be roughly 1 hour of twilight (1 lunar day × (0.5° / 360°) × a factor close to 1 for the orbital inclination) between day and night.

Comment: When the Sun sets, it gradually disappears behind the horizon. Unlike on Earth, there is no twilight. Once the _entire_ disk of the Sun is hidden by the horizon, you'll be in complete darkness; but until then you'll be standing in some fraction of its light proportional to the fraction of its area that still is visible.

Comment: Note that although there's no refraction or scattering, there *is* surface reflection.  A number of science-fiction authors get this wrong, and describe "the jet-black shadows of the Moon" -- actual shadows get significant fill lighting from the surrounding landscape.

Comment: @SolomonSlow As another comment has pointed out, the Sun's corona will be visible for some time after the Sun's disk has disappeared below the horizon. The entire corona, as visible from Earth during an eclipse, is about as bright as a full Moon (viewed from Earth). Discussions about observing "Bailey's beads" during a solar eclipse on Earth give some inkling of the experience of watching the Sun disappear below the lunar horizon.

Comment: Good points.  The Sun "setting" would be a gradual process that takes several days. My emphasis was on the fact that once it completely sets, you see none of its light because there is no atmospheric refraction

Comment: Gene Cernan said that, while standing in the shadow of the Apollo 17 LM, he could see some stars while he was outside.

Answer (score 15):

### It was daytime

This was a deliberate choice by the mission planners to avoid the obvious problems of landing at night i.e. it’s dark at night time.

The reason you can’t see stars on the Moon during the daytime is the same reason you can’t see them on Earth, your eye is adapted to the average [luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(illuminance)) in your field of view.

The day lit Moon’s surface has a more or less constant luminance of about 2.5 kcd/m<sup>2</sup> the Earth varies depending on cloud conditions between about 0.7 and 5 kcd/m<sup>2</sup>. A moonlight night on Earth is about 1.4 mcd/m<sup>2</sup> - note the k for kilo and the m for mili; we’re talking 6 orders of magnitude here.

The human eye is good, it can [adapt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation_(eye)) to cover about 10 orders of magnitude: just not all at once. Once adapted, it can cover about 3 orders of magnitude. That means, for an eye adapted to look at the Moon or the Earth, the stars are just too dim.

Comment: Of course, at nighttime you can't land on the moon because it's pitch black and you might miss it.

Comment: What a great answer.

Comment: It is fairly easy to see [Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus) during the day on this planet if you know where to look (and blocking out the Sun using a building (or if you have a spacecraft at hand...)). It ought to be even easier on the moon. Perhaps the helmet, with reflections, refractions, and filters were the real problem?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Well, there's the thing... they weren't there to take pictures of the stars. We already had better pictures (and eyewitnesses) from Earth's orbit, and of course... the trip to the Moon. And I suspect they couldn't just look _up_ in their space suits :D